# Why isn't my stackview filling with views that I am programmatically adding?

Tags: swift

I am calling the following function in viewDidLoad and I can't figure out why it isn't showing anything. I'd expect to see four horizontal blue views within the dataPointsGatheredView

```
@IBOutlet weak var dataPointsGatheredView: UIView!

func configureChart(){

    let chartParentView = UIStackView()
    chartParentView.backgroundColor = .red
    (0..<4).forEach { (index) in
        let rowView = UIView()
        rowView.backgroundColor = .blue
        chartParentView.addArrangedSubview(rowView)
    }
    chartParentView.distribution = .fillEqually
    dataPointsGatheredView.addSubview(chartParentView) // dataPointsGatheredView is a UIView segment of a stack view that I dragged in from the storyboard

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set a FRAME for your stack view.

```
self.chartParentView.frame = CGRect(x: x , y: y, width: width, height: height)
```

provide it with an x, y, width, and height

your `rowView` also does not appear to have a frame set.

Comment: since you are using `frame`, you should also setup autoresizing mask.

Comment: This solution worked, thank you. I added ```chartParentView.frame = dataPointsGatheredView.bounds``` to make use of autoresizing.